# eclipse plug-in development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-gmf

I was working on eclipse plug-in development and used the GMF framework to form the product. I want to create projects that are partially stored in the workspace and partially stored in another location. And you can load both types of projects at the same time. How to achieve this?

I'm not sure if I can use resource links or if they are related to Resourceplugins.

Comment: Do you have a question here? Hard to know what you want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.